# Mysql выборка одним запросом

Tags: mysql, select

Есть таблица Categories, вида

```
id slug tree
```

Как можно одним запросом сначала выбрать категорию где slug(это понятно), а потом по найденной с этой таблицы выбрать все где tree = выборка по slug, т.е. двумя запросами это примерно так

```
$category = SELECT * FROM category WHERE slug

$children = SELECT * FROM category WHERE tree = $category->id
```

А как одним ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Там может возникнуть проблема, если во вложенном запросе будет возвращено несколько элементов, в таком случае правильнее использовать `in`:

```
$children = SELECT c.* FROM category c WHERE c.tree in (SELECT id FROM category WHERE slug)
```

Comment: Спасибо, теперь буду знать.

Answer (score 1):

```
$children = SELECT * FROM category WHERE tree = (SELECT id FROM category WHERE slug)
```

Так не пойдет?

Comment: Думаю подойдет, спасибо.